# Is the if command the correct way to continue this code?

Tags: ruby

I'm not sure how to add a yes or no section to my script. I think I'm supposed to use the if command but I'm not sure how I would write that since all examples I see of it are using numbers. This is what I currently have,

```
print("Hi there! I would like to welcome you to this program! Please, tell me your name.: ")  
name = gets  
puts("Hello there, " + name )  
print("I'm still testing everything out so please, bear with me. Now, how old are you?: ")  
age = gets  
puts("So you're " + age.chomp + " years old. ")  
print("I am now going to ask you a few questions. I'd like you to answer as best you can. " )  
print("Are you in school? Please answer, yes or no.: ")
```

Comment: Thanks for all the information. I'll be trying out all of these to learn how each one works.

Comment: I'm unable to figure out how to get the return command to work but it did give me an idea for a slight workaround that worked. With the answers here I was able to make my script a little more complicated and I'm happy with how it turned out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the other answers you could also use a case statement to check your strings and then provide the correct response.

Eg.

```
 print "Enter your grade: "
grade = gets.chomp
case grade
when "A"
  puts 'Well done!'
when "B"
  puts 'Try harder!'
when "C"
  puts 'You need help!!!'
else
  puts "You just making it up!"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For a beginner your code is great and for the moment you don't really need to think about refactoring your code. You could add this.

```
print("Are you in school? Please answer, yes or no.: ")
answer_1 = gets.chomp
puts "your question #{answer_1}" if answer_1.eql?("yes")
```

Comment: that's a one line control statement. But you could also use the multiline if:elsif ...

Answer (score 0):

Add some checks for your inputs, heres a little recursive function for that, bear in mind, its infinite until a user inputs something that is correct.

```
def get_name
  name = gets
  if name
    puts "Hello there, " + name 
  else 
    puts 'Please put a correct name'
    return get_name
  end
end

def get_age
  age = gets
  if not age =~ /\A\d+\z/
    puts("So you're " + age.chomp + " years old. ")  
  else
    puts 'input is not a number'
    return get_age
  end
end

print("Hi there! I would like to welcome you to this program! Please, tell me your name.: ")  
get_name

print("I'm still testing everything out so please, bear with me. Now, how old are you?: ")  

get_age
print("I am now going to ask you a few questions. I'd like you to answer as best you can. " )  
print("Are you in school? Please answer, yes or no.: ")
```